# Do you need parenthesis around a Ruby require

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, is `require('my_thing')` equivalent to `require 'my_thing'`? It's just the ruby convention that you don't need to wrap a function's arguments in paranetheses right?

Comment: Yes you are correct!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, you don't need them, however, I think you need to know one important thing before deciding to ditch them all-together in your method calls (regarding your question on conventions):

### Follow Best Practices

According to the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-dsl-parens):

> Omit parentheses around parameters for methods that are part of an
>   internal DSL (e.g. Rake, Rails, RSpec), methods that have "keyword"
>   status in Ruby (e.g. attr_reader, puts) and attribute access methods.
>   Use parentheses around the arguments of all other method invocations.

Since `require` has a "keyword" status in Ruby, it's okay to not use parentheses. If, however, you made your own `my_require` method, then it would be a better idea to use them.

Comment: If you don't have parentheses with `require` and have parentheses with `my_require`, it would be ugly. It is not clear what distinguishes the two, or what you mean by keyword status. It looks to me as a circular logic/definition: Everyone omits parentheses with `puts` → `puts` is keyword-like → Everyone omits parentheses with `puts` → `puts` is keyword-like → ...

Comment: That's an interesting observation sawa, maybe put a pull request up on Github Ruby Style Guide for discussion?

Answer (score 3):

Allowing omission of parentheses around the argument is a language **feature**, not a convention.

It is a convention to omit parentheses for methods defined on the `Kernel` module that start with lower case. `require` is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need parenthesis for this. `require('my_thing')` is equivalent to `require 'my_thing'`. You are correct that this is just ruby convention.